# If any element satisfies condition

Tags: r, if-statement

```
a<-sample(1:100,replace=T)
```

I would like to have an if condition that looks at `a` and if any of the elements of `a` satisfy the condition then it executes a command.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not use `any`?

```
any(a > 100)
# FALSE

any(a > 50)
# TRUE

if (any(a > 50)) {
  # do something ...
}
```

See `?any` for details.